# Splitting after nth value

Tags: haskell

How would I write a function to split values after a certain value, for example

```
seperate :: Int -> [x] -> ([x],[x])
seperate 3 [1,4,6,9,1,2,5,7] = ([1,4,6],[9,1,2,5,7])
```

Answer (score 5):

The function you want is `splitAt`.

You can find it on [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle), by just typing the desired type into the search box. [First result!](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20%5Bx%5D%20-%3E%20%28%5Bx%5D%2C%5Bx%5D%29)